# IPhone Application Scroll to given position in UITableView when page loaded

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4.2

I want to scroll down to given row in my table view.
if I use following code inside a button event it works correctly.

```
[planTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:7 inSection:0 ] atScrollPosition:0 animated:YES];
```

But I want to do it just after the page load. Placing above code inside viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear did not work.

Any help??

Answer (score 2):

`UITableView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`, so you can just set the `contentOffset` of your tableView in `viewDidLoad:` or `viewWillAppear`.

If you need to scroll 7 table view cells down in length, calculate the height of these 7 cells (the default is 44px, but if you have custom cell heights you need to factor that in) and set the `contentOffset` to  `CGPointMake(0, *calculated height*)`. In the case of 7 44px height cells, it would be `CGPointMake(0, 308)`.

Answer (score 2):

it's kinda hack, but you also might want to perform the -scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated: with some delay, because when either -viewDidLoad or -viewDidAppear: is called, table view rows haven't been created yet so there's nothing to scroll to.

so:

```
- (void)doScrolling
{
    [planTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:7 inSection:0 ] atScrollPosition:0 animated:YES];
}
```

and in -viewDidAppear:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(doScrolling) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.3];
```

also pay attention to atScrollPosition: argument. it's enum actually:

```
typedef enum {
   UITableViewScrollPositionNone,
   UITableViewScrollPositionTop,
   UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle,
   UITableViewScrollPositionBottom
} UITableViewScrollPosition;
```

so if the row is visible and 0 is passed, no scrolling will be performed